# How to upload file to remote SSH server in VScode on Windows without drag'n'drop?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I know how to do it with drag'n'drop, but I don't want to switch between applications instead of just right-clicking and using a choose-a-file dialog. I mean, it looks like a lack of some basic functionality of Remote Explorer, cause you can download, but you can't upload files.

I tried to find an extension that could help, but they have redundant features like full sync.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to upload a file to a remote SSH server from within VSCode. It depends on your target machine you are connected to. I will assume that it is Linux.
So, basically you can use

- `scp` command - avaliable in windows and most linux distributives, easy and effective tool.
  [Scp examples](https://haydenjames.io/linux-securely-copy-files-using-scp/)
- If you are trying to upload big files or folders you would probably look at more powerful tool like `rsync` or `rclone`. These libraries allow you to effectively transfer some huge datasets, but it requires a bit of configuring. Also they are used to sync files and folders in real time.
  [Rclone](https://github.com/rclone/rclone)
  [Rsync](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync)

Comment: I use Windows as client OS in this case and look for a native UI option in the VScode itself or its plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files to remote servers can be easily done by simply dragging files to the vscode explorer